# Is a short one easier?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I came up with this short riddle while washing up:

> The right words get rid of little old me,
>
> Otherwise baffled with puzzlement be.

Hint:

> There is a clue or more on every line, take time to reflect

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This looks like a nice neat first riddle! If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site, and I hope you stick around!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the answer

> A riddle?

The right words get rid of little old me

> The puzzle will be solved if you come up with the solution

Otherwise baffled with puzzlement be.

> Riddles can indeed be baffling and puzzling.

Hint

> As well as each line having a clue, the riddle itself is a clue... because it's a riddle.

Title

> This is indeed a very short riddle.

Comment: I was one minute too late. I should have just checked the newly answered post (namely, yours) before continuing mine $\stackrel{\bullet\bullet}{\smile}$ $(+1)$

Comment: Rightly guessed. Main clues were "rid" and "puzzlement"; the right words get rid of the riddle which are the answer; which is its name. "Little old me" because it is a little riddle; "old" being a familiar term to refer to itself, which of course is the riddle.

Answer (score 2):

Is it?

> Dishwasher

I came up with this short riddle while washing up:

> Normally you need to get down to arrange and remove the contents in a dishwasher. Hence the title. The short ones like kids need not bend.

The right words get rid of little old me:

> Setting the right mode and timer makes the contents inside new.

Otherwise baffled with puzzlement be.

> Not knowing about the controls make you see it in confusion.

There is a clue or more on every line, take time to reflect

> After the cleaning time, the contents are as new that you can see your own reflection on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> An encrypted message

The right words get rid of little old me,

> The right words are the deciphering key. Once applied it replaces the original message (the little old you) with a new, readable one.

Otherwise baffled with puzzlement be.

> If the right deciphering key is not applied, you only get gibberish that will baffle you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> Germs?

The right words get rid of little old me

> The "right words" could mean the right-most words in your opening sentence - "washing up". Washing gets rid of germs, which are certainly "little" (microscopic) and "old" (microorganisms are generally believed to be the oldest living things).

Re: your hint

> "There is a clue or more on every line"
>
>  This is what makes me believe that your opening words about washing up are not superfluous but part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> A crossword

The right words get rid of little old me,

> filling in a crossword with the right words completes the crossword

Otherwise baffled with puzzlement be.

> not being able complete a crossword may leave you baffled with puzzlement